# Unable to create branch using jenkins pipeline script

Tags: git, jenkins

I have created below script to create release/test branch from develop and push it to remote.

```
stage('create branch')
        { 
            stdout = sh(script:'git checkout -b release/test3',  returnStdout: true)
            println("GIT add stdout ################ " + stdout + " ####################")
            
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'gitlogin', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) 
            {
                sh('git push origin release/test3')         
            }
        }
```

The branch is being created locally but I am unable to push it to remote .

Below is the error message:

```
+ git checkout -b release/test3
Switched to a new branch 'release/test3'
[Pipeline] echo
GIT add stdout ################  ####################
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of %GIT_USERNAME% or %GIT_PASSWORD%
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git push origin release/test3
Could not create directory '/c/Jenkins/jobs/ssa_mode/workspace/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.ssh'.
percent_expand: unknown key %H
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Kindly help to towards solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `sh()` step in `Jenkinsfile` is applicable to Linux agents. Since you are running this on a Windows agent, substitute all occurrences of `sh()` with `bat()` for proper variable expansion of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

When using git commands to create a new branch in GitHub, I have always needed to use the --set-upstream option.

I would try the sh command as `sh('git push --set-upstream origin release/test3')`. You may also need to do as Dibakar Aditya advised and use bat() instead.